# A polymorphic collection of Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, polymorphism, crtp

I've got a class `Base` from which I have two classes, `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` as defined below.

```
template <typename Derived>
class Base{
public:
    double interface(){
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->implementation();
    }
};

class DerivedA : public Base<DerivedA>{
public:
    double implementation(){ return 2.0;}
};

class DerivedB : public Base<DerivedB>{
public:
    double implementation(){ return 1.0;}
};
```

In short, I'm trying to do the following to maintain a collection of objects, some of which are `DerivedA` and some of which are `DerivedB`:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived>>
```

Which is obviously impossible beacuse I've now made the class `Derived` a templated class.

Is there any way I can create / maintain a polymorphic collection of objects?

EDIT: Unfortunately, a simple templated structure does not work as the function `implementation` is templated in my actual program -- so then `implementation` would have to be a templated pure virtual function, which cannot be. Pardon my lack of explanation.

Comment: and `Derived` is not a type in your pseudo code

Comment: Sorry, fixed the litany of typos in my example. The current (updated) post is properly formatted. There's no template metaprogramming I can do?

Comment: @quantdev I think he means `Base`. user: Why can't you ditch CRTP and use `virtual` functions? And please don't reply *purrformance*.

Comment: Not "performance", it's the fact that I would need a templated pure virtual function.

Comment: Then how about describing the *problem* you're trying to solve, instead of [describing your attempted *solution*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: "I've got a class Base". You've not. Base is not a class, it's a class template. "the function implementation is templated in my actual program". What's wrong with showing it in the vode snippet?

Comment: Why are you casting to the Derived type? Isn't that what virtual functions do for you automatically? I may be missing something but how is this different from the average, non-templated, bog-standard, run-of-the-mill polymorphic relationship between Base class and Derived class using virtual functions?

Comment: @Galik You can't have a templated (pure) virtual function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alf's suggestion is on target. It is easy to adapt it to your additional requirement. Define an interface with a pure virtual method:

```
struct BaseInterface {
    virtual ~BaseInterface() {}
    virtual double interface() = 0;
};
```

Now, your template base class can derive from the interface:

```
template <typename Derived>
class Base : BaseInterface {
public:
    double interface(){
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->implementation();
    }
};
```

Now, you can create a vector of pointers to the interface:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseInterface>>
```

Comment: Wow, despite my terrible explanation of my problem (I was in the midst of rewriting my question so that it was, at least, understandable...) you gave the exact answer I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are very welcome. Take Alf's advice to heart: Use polymorphic types when it is appropriate.

Comment: What exactly `Base` is doing? Why `Derived` cannot inherit directly from `BaseInterface`?

Comment: @n.m.: Typically, the base class does not know what type was derived from. CRTP allows the base class to have that knowledge. `Base` is using CRTP while also inheriting from `BaseInterface`. If `Derived` inherits directly from `BaseInterface`, there is no way to call `implementation()`.

Comment: "there is no way to call implementation()". Of course there is a way, from Derived::interface.

Comment: @n.m.: Only because you are requiring each `Derived` to implement `interface()` separately to call `implementation()`. `Base` does that automatically.

Comment: "automatically". Not entirely. Derived must remember to pass itself and not some other class as the template parameter. This sounds silly, but people copy the `class Derived: public Base<Derived>`, change *one* Derived to Derived1, compile cleanly and get mysterious crashes.

Comment: @n.m.: That is the essence of CRTP. You are arguing against using a well-known idiom/pattern.

Comment: CRTP is a kludge to work around a language deficiency, not a design pattern. Yes I pretty much argue against it.

Comment: @n.m.: Please take it up with Jim Coplien (and to be clear, I am not him).

Comment: Well sometimes it's reasonable (when you inject lots of stuff) but a single function isn't worth the risk IMHO.

Answer (score 13):

This answer pertains to the question **as it was at the time** of this answer.

---

Don't use CRTP, which is not dynamic polymorphism, to create dynamic polymorphism.

Use a virtual function.

That's what they're for.

```
class Base
{
private:
    virtual
    auto implementation() -> double = 0;

public:
    auto interface() -> double { return implementation(); }
};

class DerivedA
    : public Base
{
private:
    auto implementation() -> double override { return 2.0; }
};


class DerivedB
    : public Base
{
private:
    auto implementation() -> double override { return 1.0; }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a templated pure virtual function-- which is not permitted in the C++ standard.

Comment: I know, I'm sorry, I was thinking much quicker than I was typing.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Base<DerivedA>` is a completely different type compared to `Base<DerivedB>`, you are right that you can't just do something like `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>`, as it would be syntactically invalid and has no meaningful semantics with regards to C++.

One way to achieve what you want *and* preserve your current CRTP hierarchy is to create a type erasing interface (or is it what it should be called? I'm not sure...). It is basically a wrapper that defines a certain interface in which you could wrap objects that obey that interface.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>


class VirtualBase {  // Really am not sure what it should be called, sorry
    class Interface {
    public:
        virtual ~Interface() = default;
        virtual double get() = 0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    class Impl : public Interface {
        T m_impl_obj;

    public:
        Impl(T impl_obj) : m_impl_obj(std::move(impl_obj)) {}

        double get() override {
            return m_impl_obj.get();
        }
    };

    std::shared_ptr<Interface> m_obj;

public:
    template<typename T>
    VirtualBase(T obj) : m_obj(new Impl<T>(std::move(obj))) {}

    double get() {
        return m_obj->get();
    }
};


template <typename Derived>
class Base{
public:
    double get(){
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->implementation();
    }
};

class DerivedA : public Base<DerivedA>{
public:
    double get(){ return 2.0;}
};

class DerivedB : public Base<DerivedB>{
public:
    double get(){ return 1.0;}
};


int main() {
    std::vector<VirtualBase> v;
    v.emplace_back(DerivedA{});
    v.emplace_back(DerivedB{});

    for(auto b : v) {
        std::cout << b.get() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be0ba6c65ef7f079)

This is quite incomplete, but it should work, at least in my case if I need such a design. An excellent introduction, with explanations and rationales of how and why, is Sean Parent's talk at GoingNative 2013: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil . Really, you should see it, including all the other great presentations in GoingNative.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this is based on an assumption that OP actually needs virtual function templates. This is apparently not the case.

---

It is not possible to have virtual function templates.

One way to partially simulate them is the Visitor pattern. It is often used to add dynamically dispatched functionality to existing classes. The fact that this added functionality can be templatized is overlooked all too often.

A pseudocode example

```
class Base
{
    virtual void accept (Visitor*) = 0;
}

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    void accept(Visitor* v) { v->visit(this); }
}
```

class Derived2 : public Base
    {
        void accept(Visitor* v) { v->visit(this); }
    }

```
class Visitor
{
     virtual void visit (Derived1*) = 0;
     virtual void visit (Derived2*) = 0;
}

template<class X, class Y>
class FooVisitor
{
   X x; Y y;
   FooVisitor(X x, Y y): x(x), y(y) {}

     void visit (Derived1*) { x.func(y); }
     void visit (Derived2*) { y.otherfunc(x); }
  }
```

Of course all the downsides of Visitor are here as well.