# C++ vector of CRTP shared pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector, crtp

In my search for a way to store CRTP objects in a container, I found the following question:

[A polymorphic collection of Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795012/a-polymorphic-collection-of-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp-in-c)

I tryied the marked solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24795227/5475431

but the compiler is complainings erros like:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::shared_ptr<DerivedA>’ to ‘const std::shared_ptr<BaseInterface>&’
```

here is my try:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct BaseInterface {
    virtual ~BaseInterface() {}
    virtual double interface() = 0;
};

template <typename Derived>
class Base : BaseInterface {
public:
    double interface(){
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->implementation();
}
};

class DerivedA : public Base<DerivedA>{
public:
     double implementation(){ return 2.0;}
};

class DerivedB : public Base<DerivedB>{
public:
     double implementation(){ return 1.0;}
};


int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseInterface>> ar;
    ar.emplace_back(std::make_shared<DerivedA>());
return 0;
}
```

do you have any idea how to fix the compiler error, or how to solve the problem better?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to mix CRTP and run-time polymorphism?

Comment: `class Base : BaseInterface` uses private inheritance, so pointers to classes that derive from `Base` aren't convertible to `BaseInterface*`.

Comment: BTW when you paste an error message, it's _really_ useful to point out where in the code it occurred. The compiler will show _you_, so you should show us (line numbers are easy to break anyway, showing the location is better).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux first correct answer to the problem as stated. You should post an answer :)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thank very much for your remark; the problem war private derivation

Comment: @Useless the compiler is complaining the emplace_back and the I posted the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Base` should be an public inheritance of `BaseInterface`(and you also forgot `return`).
Then `ar.emplace_back(std::make_shared<DerivedA>());` well works:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YOwEetfIRfaafmY6)

```
template <typename Derived>
class Base : public BaseInterface {
public:
    double interface(){
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->implementation();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a return statement **and** `Base` should inherit from `BaseInterface`publically.

```
template <typename Derived>
struct Base : BaseInterface
{
    double interface() {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->implementation();
    }
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54271d6c8953de4b)

But beware https://stackoverflow.com/a/24795059/5470596 <-- the answer the other OP should have accepted.

Comment: While that's indeed is a bug, I would be super-suprised if it produces the diagnostic mentioned in the question.

Comment: Now you are just copy-pasting from other person's comment.

Comment: @SergeyA I fixed OP's mistake by mistake (automatism)^^ fixed. VTC typo maintained.

Comment: @SergeyA please don't be a pain.